# How to union in SUITEQL?

Tags: netsuite, suiteql

I'm trying to union two queries together. I've copy and pasted [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_156257790831.html) from the advanced queries section of the documentation but keep getting a 500 error (shown below).

```
SELECT TOP 1 id FROM transaction UNION SELECT TOP 1 id FROM transaction
```

Why doesn't this query work?

---

> {
> "type": "https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.1",
> "title": "Internal Server Error",
> "status": 500,
> "o:errorDetails": [
> {
> "detail": "An unexpected error occurred. Error ID: ld3pklv4n4wk140q60is",
> "o:errorCode": "UNEXPECTED_ERROR"
> }
> ]
> }

Comment: What is the error message that you see in the server logs?

Comment: "An unexpected error occurred. Error ID: ld3pklv4n4wk140q60is".

Answer (score 0):

For an unknown reason the solution is to wrap the union in parentheses.

```
SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT TOP 1 id FROM transaction
     UNION ALL
     SELECT TOP 1 id FROM transaction
)
```

CREDIT: I found an example buried on an [archived slack thread](https://archive.netsuiteprofessionals.com/t/344905/does-suiteql-support-union):

[image: Screencapture of the archived site]